# Using UnitySteer's SteerForPath in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried asking this question on Unity Answers, but I don't seem to be getting an answer there, so I thought I'd try here

I'm trying to use the SteerForPath script in UnitySteer 2.5 with AngryAnt's Path 2.0 for a racing game, but I'm not sure how to: I can set up the waypoints in Path, but the SteerForPath script doesn't provide a way for a path to be linked to it in the inspector. Can anyone help me with how to link a waypoint path to UnitySteer's SteerForPath? It doesn't have to be AngryAnt's Path, but if it isn't it would be helpful if you could provide a tutorial or demo as to how to set up a waypoint path in that other system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to SteerForPath.cs in the Steering package from [Arges-Systems](http://arges-systems.com/blog/category/unitysteer/)?  If so, you're better off using [SteerForPathSimplified.cs](https://github.com/ricardojmendez/UnitySteer/blob/development/Behaviors/SteerForPathSimplified.cs)

This version has a publicly available property for assigning a 'Path'.  Though the Arges-Systems author [does state](http://arges-systems.com/blog/2011/02/21/unitysteer-2-1-released/) (halfway down in comments) that his SteerForPathSimplified.cs is not necessarily designed to work with AngryAnt's code, but you should be able to quickly modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: I tried to look at the SteerForPathSimplified.cs as you suggested. While the code itself displays the public property field, that field doesn't show up in the Unity Inspector. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a problem with Unity (I'm using Unity 3.5.5f3)?

Comment: Unity inspector will only show properties for certain datatypes like int, float, double, Vector3, Quaternion, etc.  It will not show custom data types.

Comment: I see. It leaves me the problem of how to assign the path to the script, unfortunately. Would the solution be to directly edit the script, or use another script to assign the path? Directly editing the script breaks abstraction (admittedly not really an issue, but it makes the programmer in me uncomfortable), while I'm unsure as to how to use another script to assign the path.

Comment: Modify the SteerForPathSimplified script so it has a public array of Vector3's (each point a location on your path) and then create a method to convert to a Path.